# how to create a table in php with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table for a leaderboard which displays users high scores for a game. I am using my sql to hold the data and php to get that data and put it into a table. when i go to this page on the site however, the page loads but all the php code shows up instead of the table. i dont know what im doing wrong, how do i get the php to display the table?
    
    
        
            Sokoban Game

```
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                    <h1>Sokoban</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="nav">
                <div class="nav_wrapper">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li><li>
                        <a href="#">Play</a></li><li>
                        <a href="#">Help</a></li><li>
                        <a href="#">Leaderboards</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="highScores.html">High Scores</a></li>
                                <li><a href="topLevels.html">Top Levels</a></li>
                                <li><a href="mostCompleted.html">Most completed</a></li>
                            </ul>    
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="leftSideBar">
            </div>

            <div class="mainContent">

                <h2>High Scores</h2>

                <div class = "leaderboard">
                        <?php

    // Get a connection for the database
    require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');

    // Create a query for the database
    $query = "SELECT rankNo, username, highScores FROM Users INNER JOIN leaderboardHighScores";

    // Get a response from the database by sending the connection
    // and the query
    $response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    // If the query executed properly proceed
    if($response){

    echo '<table>
    <tr><td><b>Rank</b></td>
    <td><b>Username</b></td>
    <td><b>High Score</b></td></tr>';


    // mysqli_fetch_array will return a row of data from the query
    // until no further data is available
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){

    echo '<tr><td>' .
    $row['rankNo'] . '</td><td>' .
    $row['username'] . '</td><td>' .
    $row['highScores'] . '</td><td>';

    echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';

    } else {

    echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";

    echo mysqli_error($dbc);

    }

    // Close connection to the database
    mysqli_close($dbc);


    ?>  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rightSideBar">
                <h3>Sign in</h3>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="txtBox" /></br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Password" class="txtBox" /></br></br>

                <input type="button" value="login" class="btn"/>

                <h2>Sign up<h2>
                <input type="button" value="Create account" class="btn"/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>                
</html>
```

Comment: if you see raw php: is the page *.php? running on a server with php

Comment: if your are testing on a  local server, make sure apache is running and the file extension is .php